# Why won't Game Maker run my game on Android?

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop, game-maker

I have the pro version of Game Maker from here: http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker
The game I created won't run on my phone. I have android as the target and I clicked run game,  it compiles then gets stuck. heres the full log:

### Log

```
"C:\Users\Nightwing\AppData\Roaming\GameMaker-Studio\GMAssetCompiler.exe" /fU="C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Projects\gm_ttt_53223\a97240.txt" /c /m=android /studio  /config="Default" /tgt=8 /tg="C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Projects\gm_ttt_53223\\TextureGroups.txt" /to="C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Projects\gm_ttt_53223\\TextureOptions.txt" /obob=True /obpp=False /obru=True /obes=False /i=3 /cvm /tp=1024 /mv=1 /iv=0 /rv=0 /bv=1464 /gn="PaperRoids" /td="C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Projects" /cd="C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Cache" /sh=True /dbgp="6502" /o="C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Projects\gm_ttt_53223\PaperRoids" /optionsini="C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Projects\gm_ttt_53223\gm_ttt_62571\PaperRoids.ini"   "C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Projects\PaperRoids.gmx\PaperRoids.project.gmx"
Reading project file....finished.
Remove DnD...finished.
Compile Constants...finished.
Compile Scripts...finished.
Compile Objects...finished.
Compile Timelines...finished.
Compile Triggers...finished.
Compile Rooms...finished.
Compile Extensions...finished.
Final Compile...finished.
Saving IFF file... C:\Users\Nightwing\Documents\GameMaker\Projects\gm_ttt_53223\PaperRoids\PaperRoids.zip
Writing Chunk... GEN8
Writing Chunk... OPTN
Writing Chunk... EXTN
Writing Chunk... SOND
Writing Chunk... AGRP
Writing Chunk... SPRT
Writing Chunk... BGND
Writing Chunk... PATH
Writing Chunk... SCPT
Writing Chunk... SHDR
Writing Chunk... FONT
Writing Chunk... TMLN
Writing Chunk... OBJT
Writing Chunk... ROOM
Writing Chunk... DAFL
Writing Chunk... TPAGE
Writing Chunk... CODE
Writing Chunk... VARI
Writing Chunk... FUNC
Writing Chunk... STRG
Writing Chunk... TXTR
0 Compressing texture... writing texture texture_0.png... 
Writing Chunk... AUDO
Writing Chunk... SCPT
Writing Chunk... DBGI
Writing Chunk... INST
Writing Chunk... STRG
Stats : GMA : Instance=5, Global=2
"C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb" get-state device
"C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell echo $INTERNAL_STORAGE
"C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
/storage/emulated/legacy "C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb" get-state 
device
"C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell echo $INTERNAL_STORAGE
"C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
/storage/emulated/legacy "C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell [ -d /storage/emulated/legacy/GMstudio ] && cd /storage/emulated/legacy/GMstudio; rm -r *;  
override rwxr-xr-x root:root for 'acct'?
```

It just hangs at " override rwxr-xr-x root:root for 'acct'? " until I click stop webserver. I triple checked that Game Maker could find Android SDK, NDK and JDK, all good there. I followed this tutorial: http://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/216753498-GameMaker-Studio-Android-SDK-and-NDK-setup-
ADB recognizes my devices, I Tried it on my Galaxy S4 and Nexus 7, both running Lollipop. I also uninstalled and reinstalled Game Maker and Android SDK. All help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your devices rooted?

Comment: No, do they have to be for Game Maker? I can root the nexus 7 if needed.

Comment: Is `C:\sdk\platform-tools\adb` the correct file location? Is that something you set? Should that be adb.exe?

Comment: I Installed SDK to that directory and just pointed Game Maker to that directory. Not sure if it should be adb.exe, dont think so, as Game Maker just sees where it's installed and runs adb automatically. On a side note Game Maker is communicating with my devices, it sees they're connected  and when I open a file explorer on them I can see what Game Maker tried to transfer.

Comment: It looks like there's a folder permissions issue, although I can't figure out why.

Comment: Yeah,  Is it possible because the nexus has emulated storage and the S4 puts everything on internal storage by default? Not really sure why that would have any permission issues..I wouldn't think it would need root access.